# Why is the state variable value lost in a function in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I change the value of the variable with the TextBox I want to print the current value in the dummy function. Instead of the new number I type into the textbox I get the value **NaN** which tells me its treated as a number but the value is gone. How can I preserve that? I thought the state is being kept everywhere.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {

function dummy(){
    return (<div>USERID von dummy: {USERID}</div>);
  }

  const [USERID, setUSERID] = React.useState(9);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <h1>REACT - AXIOS</h1>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <table>
        <tr>
          UserID: <TextField onChange={text => setUSERID(parseInt(text))} variant="outlined" name="userid" label="userid" id="userid" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            {dummy()}
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style={{ marginTop: 30 }} >
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems like you need to add `value` prop: `<TextField value={USERID} onChange={text => setUSERID(parseInt(text))} variant="outlined" name="userid" label="userid" id="userid" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of syntax I assume you're using MUI, so the function `onChange` returns an event Object, you can't parse it to number, you must get the value first:

`<TextField onChange={e => setUSERID(parseInt(e.target.value))} value={USERID} {...rest} />`

Comment: and this is the simple solution - thank you, you saved me a lot of time!!!